# How to find the index of columns with at least one non-zero element?

Tags: matlab

Given a binary matrix in Matlab, I would like to find the index of the columns that have at least one non-zero element. How can I do this?

```
B
     1     1     0     0     0
     0     0     0     1     0
     0     1     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `any` and `find` to find the indices of the columns:

```
indices = find(any(B,1))
```

Use `any(B,1)` to find the columns with at least one non-zero element, then use `find` to obtain the indices of these columns.